# Removing camel route is not removing tibco queue receivers count

Tags: apache-camel

We have a stand alone application where we should be able to stand up JMS listeners using database configuration dynamically. If there is any change in the concurrentConsumers count in the database, then we need to update the listeners accordingly. We are using camel 2.16.2 and Tibco 6.3.0. Precisely, the below are our requirements.

1. Ability to add and remove JMS listeners dynamically.
   To achieve this, we are creating our OwnRouteBuilder (which extends camel RouteBuilder) and adding it using camelContext.addRoutes(RouteBuilder) dynamically which is working as expected.
2. Ability to increase or decrease JMS listeners dynamically. 
   To achieve this, initially we tried to stop the route, update concurrentConsumers count, and then start route. It is working fine only when we increase the concurrentConsumers count. But its not working if we decrease( its not changing the concurrentConsumers count).We can still see the same receivers count from tibco console.

As an alternate solution , we tried with camelContext.stopRoute(routeId) and then camelContext.removeRoute(routeId) so that we can add a fresh route with updated concurrentConsumers count later. In this case also, though it is stopping the routes from consuming messages, it is not changing the receivers count from tibco console.

I tried with camelContext.removeEndpoints(endpointUri), camelContext.shutdownRoute(routeId), camelContext.removeRouteDefinition(routedefinition) methods.
But all these methods only stopping the routes from consuming messages, but not clearing those receivers count from tibco console.
The receivers count from tibco console is becoming zero only when we terminate the application.

Is there any way that we can make it from camel so that those receivers count from tibco console becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the concurrentConsumer counts dynamically at runtime using JMX to set the values on the JMX attribute on the endpoint. Then the route dont have to be stopped/removed/started etc.